# Angular services

Tags: angularjs, service, factory

I am trying to share an id between controllers in angular

I have created a service as follows:

```
app.factory("idService", function() {
    var id;
    addId = function(id) {
        id = id;
    };
    getId = function() {
        return id;
    };    
});
```

In my controller I am trying to use this service as follows:

```
app.controller('photoFormController', ['$scope', '$http', 'idService' , function($scope,   $http, idService) {

       $scope.id = idService.getId();
}]);
```

I am getting an error of can't call method of undefined, obviously I am injecting the service incorrectly. Can someone help ?

**EDIT:**

Based on the solution below, the service no longer generates errors, however I am unable to get the id varaible back, I can see that it gets set from one controller, however it remains undefined in when retrieving :

```
app.factory("idService", function() {
    var id;
    addId = function(id) {
        id = id;
        console.log("added id of: " + id);
    };
    getId = function() {
        console.log("trying to return : " + id);
        return id;
    };
    return {
        addId: addId,
        getId: getId
    };
});
```

Comment: In the `addId` function `id = id` has no sense, since it assigns first argument to itself

Comment: @Vadim my mistake, sorted now ...

Answer (score 6):

You need to return an object inside `factory`. This returned object is your service instance:

```
app.factory("idService", function() {
    var _id; //use _id instead to avoid shadowing your variable with the same name id
    var addId = function(id) { //use var to avoid creating a property on the global object
        _id = id;
    }; 
    var getId = function() { //use var to avoid creating a property on the global object
        return _id;
    };    

    return {
        addId : addId ,
        getId : getId 
    };
});
```

Comment: I am no longer getting the error, however I am unable to get back the set variable ... could this be a timing issue ?

Comment: @avrono: try `var _id;` to avoid shadowing your variable with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to place the id within an object.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremythuff/nvobwubc/1/)

This idea is as follows:

```
myApp.controller('ctrl1', function($scope, myservice) {
  $scope.updateId = function() {
    myservice.setId($scope.input)
  };
});


myApp.controller('ctrl2', function($scope, myservice) {
    $scope.data = myservice.getData();
});

myApp.service('myservice', function() {

  var myservice = this;

  var data = {};

  myservice.setId = function(newValue) {
    data.id = newValue;
  };

  myservice.getData = function() {
    return data;
  }

});
```

This way the data object that you get from your service sort of static, and the mutable member that you are outputting is contained within it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a service in order to share some variable, just use `value()`:

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app',[]).
  value('share', {id: 123}).
  run(['share', function(share) {
    console.log(share.id); // <= 123
    share.id = 345;
  }]).
  controller('appController', ['$scope', 'share', function($scope, share) {
    $scope.id = share.id; // <= 345
  }]);
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/m55hmFgBvi1rwVsYMeKU?p=preview

Comment: I will try this, seems simpler than the service option ... does this method work across multiple controllers ?

Comment: @avrono Yes, it works like a service that you can inject anywhere, just like regular services. It is also a singleton, so there will be only one such value that is shared across the app.

Comment: @avrono: using a `service` or just a `value` depends on your requirement. If you just need a plain value, use `value` is better, in case you need to add more logic to `addId` (like validate the parameter) and `getId`, you should use a service.

Comment: Thanks all, I just a single value, basically controllers within controllers opening a Modal, I need to pass the id around between controller, modal etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Example of service which store data between controllers:

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('youService', youService);

youService.$inject = ['$rootScope'];
function youService($rootScope) {
    var service = {};
    var questions = [];
    // Data
    function getData() {
        return questions;
    };
    function setData(newQuestion) {
        questions.push(newQuestion);
    };
    function resetData() {
        questions = {};
    };

    // Services
    service.getData = getData;
    service.setData = setData;
    service.resetData = resetData;
    return service;
};
```

In controller:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('yourController', yourController);
stepFourController.$inject = ['$scope', 'youService'];
function yourController($scope, youService){
    // Get saved data from service
    $scope.model = youService.getData();
    // Set data to service
    youService.setData($scope.model);
    // Reset data in service
    youService.resetData();
};
```

Comment: Use of rootScope in services is bad ! Do not inject scope or rootScope in business intelligence.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to share data between controller is through services or factories
The service can be written as:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.service('shareId', [function () {
    var shareIdService = this;
    shareIdService.id = '';
    shareIdService.setId = function (id) {
        shareIdService.id = id;
    }
    shareIdService.getId = function () {
        return shareIdService.id;
    }
}]);
```

or factory may be written like as

```
myApp.factory('shareId', [function () {
    var id = '';
    return {
        setId:function (id){
            id=id;
        },
        getId:function (){
            return id;
        }
    }
}])
```